# Node module missing from dist build using Angular2 cli

Tags: node.js, npm, angular, package.json

I'm using the Angular 2 cli to scaffold and build my Angular 2 website, I'm now trying to add authentication to it and added the angular2-jwt node module using

```
npm install angular2-jwt --save
```

it has added the module to the package.json but is not being placed in the dist folder when I run

```
ng build
```

What else do I need to do to get it in the dist folder or diagnose what's going wrong.

Here's the package,json:

```js
{
  "name": "depots",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng server",
    "postinstall": "typings install --ambient",
    "lint": "tslint src/**/*.ts",
    "format": "clang-format -i -style=file --glob=src/**/*.ts",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.9",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.8",
    "clang-format": "^1.0.35",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "ng2-table": "^1.0.0-beta.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.20",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-cli": "0.0.*",
    "angular-cli-github-pages": "^0.2.0",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.0",
    "glob": "^6.0.4",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^2.4.0",
    "karma": "^0.13.15",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.6",
    "protractor": "^3.0.0",
    "silent-error": "^1.0.0",
    "tslint": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.7",
    "typings": "^0.6.6",
    "ts-node": "^0.5.5"
  }
}
```

Here's the contents of ember-cli-build.js

```js
/* global require, module */

var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: []
  });
  return app.toTree();
}
```

Comment: Could you also provide the content of your `angular-cli-build.js` file? Thanks!

Comment: I've added it, its actually called ember-cli just now as its based on ember and still in development